# Set where $f$ is differentiable has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$. If $E$ is the set of points where $f$ is differentiable, and $\mu(E)=0$ (Lebesgue measure), then show $\mu(f(E))=0$.

Comment: Check out Lemma 7.25 on page 153 [here](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf).

Comment: A much more general result is proved in Measure Theory by Bogachev.